# Camera view does not show any object

Tags: camera, visibility

I have a strange effect with one blend file.

When I switch from the viewport view to camera view the camera does not see the object, although it is in the view. There rendered image shows the object again.

To test this effect I deleted all objects but one.

This is the scene:
[image: This is the scene]

This is what the camera view shows:
[image: This is what the camera view shows]

This is the final render:
[image: This is the final render]

The test file (1 MB) can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/t/133lAebH3QobnHLt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In camera view press <kbd>Home</kbd> key on keyboard.

Keyboards without <kbd>Home</kbd> key can press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

This is a shortcut for command **Frame Camera Bounds** and can be found from **View** menu under **Cameras**.

[image: Frame Camera Bounds]

Comment: It took a while until I found the home key on a Mac keyboard. It is Fn + Left arrow. The menu command is View > Camera > Frame Camera Bounds.

Comment: Nice. I added your comment to the answer.